# Square root question with ^3

Tags: radicals

I'm trying to write $(\sqrt{3}/\sqrt{6})^3$ to simplest form possible which should be $1/4\sqrt{2}$.

This is what I tried: (√3/√6)^3 = (√3/√6 * √6/√6)^3 = (√18/6)^3 = √18^3/6^3 = √5832 / 216 =... I'm kinda stuck here and do not know what mathematics rule I have to apply.

Could you help me with showing where my miscalculation is and helping me with step by step?

Edit: I'm also new to stackexchange so I have no idea if i provided enough information

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Here's an admittedly rather long but very helpful tutorial on MathJax formatting, which will make your question much easier for everyone (including you, likely) to read:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @RobertHoward Thank you. I already see somebody has edit it and put it in format. For my further posts I will use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three things to note are:

$(\sqrt{a})^3 = (\sqrt{a})^2 \sqrt {a} = a*\sqrt{a}$.

And:

$\sqrt{a*b} = \sqrt{a}*\sqrt{b}$ (assuming $a$ and $b$ are both positive.)

And, obviously:

$(\frac ab)^k = \frac {a^k}{b^k}$.

So:

$(\frac {\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 6})^3 = (\frac {\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 2*\sqrt 3})^3 = (\frac 1{\sqrt 2})^3 = \frac 1{(\sqrt 2)^3} = \frac 1{2\sqrt 2}$.

And if you have one of those textbooks that insist you can't have a radical in then denominator:

$\frac 1{2\sqrt 2}= \frac {\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}} = \frac {\sqrt{2}}4$.

...

To finish what you began:

$ (√3/√6)^3 = (√3/√6 * √6/√6)^3 = (√18/6)^3 = √18^3/6^3 = √5832 / 216 =$

$\frac{\sqrt{5832}}{216} = \frac{\sqrt {54^2*2}}{216}= \frac {54\sqrt{2}}{216}=\frac {\sqrt 2}{4}$.

Which should be a lesson to you to simplify as you go along. It'd have been easier to do:

$(\frac {\sqrt{18}}{6})^2 =( \frac {\sqrt{9*2}}{6})^3 = (\frac {3*\sqrt 2}{6})^3 = (\frac {\sqrt 2}2)^3 = \frac {\sqrt{2^3}}{2^3} = \frac {\sqrt{2^2*2}}{2^3} = \frac {2 \sqrt 2}{2^3} = \frac {\sqrt 2}{2^2} =\frac {\sqrt 2}{4}$.

If you've learned this there is alson $\sqrt[k]{a} = a^{\frac 1k}$.

So $(\frac {\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 6})^3 = $$(\frac {3^{\frac 12}}{6^{\frac 12}})^3 $$= \frac {3^{\frac 32}}{6^{\frac 32}} = (\frac 36)^{1\frac 12}=(\frac 12)^{1\frac 12} =\frac 12*\sqrt {\frac 12} = \frac 1{2\sqrt{2}}$.

Moral:  In Math, there are more than one way to do things.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. That first rule made it clear. According to my book it should be `1/4√2`

Comment: Yoour book has a typo.

Comment: I want to thank you for this insight and explanation. There are still 20 exercise left which I will try with the rules you provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$ \left(\frac {\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 6}\right)^3 =$$

$$\left(\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^3 =\frac {1}{(\sqrt 2)^3}=$$

$$\frac {1}{2\sqrt 2}= \frac {\sqrt 2}{4} $$

You do not get $\frac {1}{4\sqrt 4}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was a typo as my book says it should be `1/4√2`

Comment: The answer$ \frac {1}{2\sqrt 2}$ is the same as (1/4)√2 which is your book's answer. They rationalized it.